# Google AppScript Function Timing Out on Slow Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a custom function with google appscript for google sheets, and it runs fine on a test workbook - but it times out every time on the live sheet. Is it possible that this is because the target sheet is just too large, or is there something wrong with my code?

The target workbook has 25+ pages - the two sheets in particular I am trying to fix have 500 000+ cells between them. Most of the columns in these two sheets are formulas copy-pasted down.

On a test workbook with the same number of rows but no active formulas, my appscript formulas run in less than a second according to the Duration in the Developer Hub. But the exact same function on the live sheet - I cancelled it after 1232 seconds.

This is the meat of my function:

```
var values = range.getValues();
range.clearContent();
range.setValues(values);
```

Range is about 9000 cells.
Is it me? Or is it this bloated spreadsheet?

Comment: Just to be clear, you call this a custom function so are you using it as a cell function or a stand alone script.

Comment: Stand Alone Script was probably a poor choice of words.  I just me a standard script that you run from a menu or call as a function.

Comment: It's a standalone script, not an in-cell function. I've been running it either through a sidebar menu or directly from the script editor.

Comment: If you would like to share the code we can look at it.  But really I don't know.

Comment: 500k cells with formulas take a lot of time to load, and the script won't execute until they finish.